# Quiz maker for revision based on user's needs

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm looking for WP plugin or any external toll. I have a LMS webpage with several courses. I would like to have a chance for my users to create quiz with questions for revision. In this quiz generator, users should be able to choose questions from different categories, choose number of questions and do this quiz as many times as they want.

For example:
My user wants to generate quiz which includes questions from Geography, Math and Science. He wants 100 questions in total. I will have a database of my questions. This toll should generate a quiz based on user needs (categories, number of questions).

I was looking for more than 2 hours and I did not find anything that suits my needs. Does anyone know anything that can help me?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also looking for a similar plugin, came across a couple of interesting ones. Maybe they’ll suit you too - Quiz Maker, Riddle Quiz https://wordpress.org/plugins/quiz-maker/

Comment: This is a link-only answer. Please don't post under questions asking for tool recomendations.

Answer (score 0):

try these Plugins for WordPress 1)LearnDash, 2)WP Quiz .https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-quiz/